# Jquery Datatable pagination checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, pagination, datatables

I have a html table with checkboxes and pagination and my problem is that i can only select objects from current page.. could anyone help me?

```
<form action="{% url 'tag:selected' %}" method="get">
  <table id="dt" class="table table-bordered table-hover responsive" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"></th>
                <th></th>
        <td>Name</td>
          <td>Frequency</td>
        <td>Environment</td>
          <td>Peak Temperature</td>
          <td>Mounting Method</td>
          <td>Standards</td>
          <td>Memory</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for tags in all_tags %}

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="selected" value="{{ tags.id}}"></td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'tag:detail' tags.id %}"> <img src="{{ tags.tag_image.url }}" style="display:block;
width: 80px; height:80px; margin:auto;"></a></td>
        <td>{{ tags.tag_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ tags.tag_frequency}}</td>
        <td>{{ tags.tag_environment }}</td>
          <td>{{ tags.tag_peak_temperature }}</td>
          <td>{{ tags.tag_mounting_method }}</td>
          <td>{{ tags.tag_standards }}</td>
          <td>{{ tags.tag_memory }}</td>
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table><input class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right; margin-right:5%; margin-bottom:2%; margin-top:-3%; "type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
```

and here is my javascript code for checkboxes:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selected');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you use for pagination process?

Comment: im using this one: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: Use `var allSelectedRows = oTable.$("input:checked", {"page": "all"});`

Comment: that didnt work :/

Comment: Please specify the error?

Comment: well im not any pro with js so im not sure how it should be, but when i did add that one there it didnt select anything or just one, never all.. but if someone would know how to use this datatable https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/ and add data from django database it would be perfect..